# Linear programming modelling question

Tags: linear-programming

The problem is:

> A production company requires different amounts of renewable resource
> on different days of the week. The units of renewable resource
> required on each day is given as follows: Monday: $17$ Tuesday: $13$
> Wednesday: $15$ Thursday: $19$ Friday: $14$ Saturday: $16$ Sunday: $11$
>
> For some production reason, the renewable resource must be used five
> consecutive days from the day which it begins to be used. And then it
> becomes unusable and needs two days to be renewed.
>
> For example, $2.6$
> units of resource which are used from Monday to Friday must be off for
> renewal on Saturday and Sunday. The company has to meet its daily
> requirements using the considered renewable resource. Formulate an LP
> for the company such that the total amount (in units) of renewable
> resource required can be minimized subject to the daily requirements.

I believe this should be the  objective function

$x_k =$ renewable resource units used during day $k$

$MIN = 17x_1 + 13x_2 + 15x_3 + 19x_4 + 14x_5 + 16x_6 + 11x_7$

However I'm a bit lost when looking at how to interpret as a constraint, the renewable resource being used over $5$ days and not the next $2$ days.

Will it look something like this?
$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 - x_6 - x_7 \leq 78$
etc?

Answer (score 1):

If the resource e.g. is a software engineer with five days shift and two days off :–), it makes sense:

Let $x_k$ be the amount which is put in use starting at day $k$.

The objective is to minimize $\sum_k x_k$.

At day $k$ we have $u_k$ of the resource in use where
$$
u_k = \sum_{i=0}^4 x_{((k-1-i) \bmod 7)+1}
$$
e.g 
$$
u_3 = x_3 + x_2 + x_1 + x_7 + x_6
$$
The requirements give the constraints
$$
u_k \ge r_k 
$$
e.g.
$$
x_3 + x_2 + x_1 + x_7 + x_6 \ge 15
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this seems correct. If i may ask, would there be a way to incorporate uk into the objective function?

Comment: You could use $\sum u_k/5$ which should be the same as $\sum x_k$.

Comment: Note: This models a production cycle which is established. If one starts with production fresh on a monday then there are no prior resources in use. I assume one would need information on what day of week production starts and how long it would run to be precise.

Comment: So if i were to have uk/5 as the variable in the objective function, how would i interpret the constraints in terms of just uk, without using x?

Comment: I think i've figured it out, using a similar version of yours, i posted as an answer

Comment: The constraints are simply $u_k\ge r_k$, e.g, $u_1\ge 17$. You can formulate the problem in terms of the $u_k$, but you want to know the $x_k$. So I would expand everything in terms of the $x_k$.

Answer (score 0):

$MIN = x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7$

$x1 + x7 + x6 + x5 + x4 >= 17 $

$x2 + x1 + x7 + x6 + x5 >= 13$

$x3 + x2 + x1 + x7 + x6 >= 15$

$x4 + x3 + x2 + x1 + x7 >= 19$

$x5 + x4 + x3 + x2 + x1 >= 14$

$x6 + x5 + x4 + x3 + x2 >= 16$

Comment: This is wrong, You do not use the resources from the future.

Comment: im not sure how to adjust it

Comment: Ahh i understand now.